# How to get around 'AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'' in this code?

Tags: python, list

In this practice program in which the user is asked to remove some subjects from a list of subjects, and at the end display the modified list. I'm getting:

`'AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'' error on line 8 [to_remove = to_remove.append(next)--- this line]`

```
list1 = ["science", "maths", "english", "social", "economics", "pe"]
print(list1)
to_remove = []
to_remove = input("Enter the subject you like to remove: ")
query = input("Do you like to remove more? ")
while query != "no":
    next = input("Enter the subject name: ")
    to_remove = to_remove.append(next)
    query = input("Would you like to remove more? ")
print("Thank you\n")

for i in to_remove:
    list1.remove(i)
print("Here is your modified list:\n")
print(list1)
```

Comment: You first initialize `to_remove` to a list, but on the next line you set it to a string instead. Strings don't have an `append` method, but lists do.

Comment: Oh. Got it. Any idea how I can enter the user input into the list then?

Comment: Just use the append method for the first input. (And don't assign anything to the return value)

Comment: What do you mean by "enter into" the list? What should happen as a result?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel the intention was to add all the subject the user wishes to remove into a list and then remove those from the original list1

Comment: Okay, so. See where the code says `to_remove.append(next)`? That's the code that you will use to put things into the `to_remove` list inside the loop, correct? So. Before the loop, you want to put the result from the `input` call into the loop. What do you imagine the code for that would look like, based on that reasoning? (What I'm getting at is: I am confused that you ask how to do something, that you have already shown how to do.)

Answer (score 0):

The name of the list and the input variable were the same. So, there was a conflict. You were trying to access the append method of the input string. Also, the first input you enter was never stored in a list, so fixed that too

```
list1 = ["science", "maths", "english", "social", "economics", "pe"]
print(list1)
to_remove_list = [] #Changed the name here
to_remove = input("Enter the subject you like to remove: ")
to_remove_list.append(to_remove) # Your first element is now appending to list
query = input("Do you like to remove more? ")
while query != "no":
    next = input("Enter the subject name: ")
    to_remove = to_remove_list.append(next)
    query = input("Would you like to remove more? ")
print("Thank you\n")
for i in to_remove_list:
    list1.remove(i)
print("Here is your modified list:\n")
print(list1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments and answers, the issue was I declared to_remove as a list and later tried to store a string input in it instead. So when I tried to append, I was trying to append to a string [which is not possible], thus the error.  Here's the code that fixed the error.

```
list1 = ["science", "maths", "english", "social", "economics", "pe"]
print(list1)
to_remove = []
to_remove.append(input("Enter the subject you like to remove: "))
query = input("Do you like to remove more? ")
while query != "no":
    to_remove.append(input("Enter the subject name: "))
    query = input("Would you like to remove more? ")
print("Thank you\n")
for i in to_remove:
    list1.remove(i)
print("Here is your modified list:\n")
print(list1)
```